# Sql select query based on a column value

Tags: sql, select, join

I have a `Table1` like this:

```
ApplicableTo IdApplicable
---------------------------
Dept              1
Grade             3
section           1
Designation       2
```

There other tables like:

`tblDept`:

```
ID     Name
1       dept1
2       baking
3       other
```

`tblGrade`:

```
ID      Name
1       Grd1
2       Manager
3       gr3
```

`tblSection`:

```
id      Name
1       Sec1
2       sec2
3       sec3
```

`tblDesignation`:

```
id      Name
1       Executive
2       Developer
3       desig3
```

What I need is a query for `table1` in such a way that gives me

```
ApplicableTo (table1)
Name (from the relevant table based on the value in `ApplicableTo` column)
```

Is this possible?

Desired Result:

```
eg: ApplicableTo IdApplicable Name
      Dept            1       dept1
      grade           3       gr3
      Section         1       sec1
      Designation     2       Developer.
```

This is the result I desire.

Comment: Can you post a sample desired query result, I couldn't understand the expected result.

Comment: I want the ApplicableTo column from table1 as it is, but in the place of IdApplicable I want the Name from relavant table...

Comment: eg: ApplicableTo IdApplicable Name
      Dept            1       dept1
      grade           3       gr3
      Section         1       sec1
      Designation     2       Developer.
This is the result I desire.

Comment: i have edited my question and included my desired result.

Comment: It's possible but I wouldn't recommend it.Your column IdApplicable has a multi-purpose. Generally all values in a single column should come from the same domain, the same value in different rows should have the same meaning. This is not true of your Department and Section rows. It would be better to have separate DeptId, GradeId columns.

Comment: I agree with your point @ Steve Ford but I'm not the database developer here. I'm simply to do this task without manipulating the table structure. Thanks Anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CASE here,

```
SELECT ApplicableTo,
       IdApplicable,
       CASE 
         WHEN ApplicableTo = 'Dept' THEN (SELECT Name FROM tblDept WHERE tblDept.ID = IdApplicable) 
         WHEN ApplicableTo = 'Grade' THEN (SELECT Name FROM tblGrade WHERE tblGrade.ID = IdApplicable)
         WHEN ApplicableTo = 'Section' THEN (SELECT Name FROM tblSection WHERE tblSection.ID = IdApplicable)
         WHEN ApplicableTo = 'Designation' THEN (SELECT Name FROM tblDesignation WHERE tblDesignation.ID = IdApplicable)
       END AS 'Name'
FROM Table1
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like the following so the applicable to becomes part of the JOIN predicate:

```
SELECT  t1.ApplicableTo, t1.IdApplicable, n.Name
FROM    Table1 AS t1
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  ID, Name, 'Dept' AS ApplicableTo
            FROM    tblDept
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  ID, Name, 'Grade' AS ApplicableTo
            FROM    tblGrade
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  ID, Name, 'section' AS ApplicableTo
            FROM    tblSection
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  ID, Name, 'Designation' AS ApplicableTo
            FROM    tblDesignation
        ) AS n
            ON n.ID = t1.IdApplicable 
            AND n.ApplicableTo = t1.ApplicableTo
```

I would generally advise against this approach, although it may seem like a more consice approach, you would be better having 4 separate nullable columns in your table:

```
ApplicableTo | IdDept | IdGrade | IdSection | IdDesignation
-------------+--------+---------+-----------+---------------
Dept         |    1   |  NULL   |    NULL   |     NULL
Grade        |  NULL  |    3    |    NULL   |     NULL
section      |  NULL  |   NULL  |      1    |     NULL
Designation  |  NULL  |   NULL  |    NULL   |       2
```

This allows you to use foreign keys to manage your referential integrity properly.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve that is to add an extra column in table1 to keep the table where id is refferred to. Otherwise you can't know in which table the applicable id is reffered to.

Or you can create the applicable id in a way that you can extract the table afterwords from it for example a1 for id 1 in tblDept. And then use [case] (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) (for mysql) in order to make the correct Join.